# Power Query SQL code issue

Tags: sql, excel

I'm trying to run this SQL code in Power Query but keep getting the following error Message:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'

The SQL code I'm using is

```
SELECT Groups.GroupName, AgentTeams.TeamName, Agent.Firstname, Agent.Lastname, CRC.Description, Count(History.HistoryID) AS CountOfHistoryID
FROM ((GroupAgent 
INNER JOIN Groups ON GroupAgent.GroupID = Groups.GroupID) 
INNER JOIN ((Agent LEFT JOIN History ON Agent.AgentID = History.AgentID) 
LEFT JOIN CRC ON History.CRC = CRC.CRC) ON GroupAgent.AgentID = Agent.AgentID)
INNER JOIN (AgentTeams 
INNER JOIN AgentStartDates ON AgentTeams.TeamID = AgentStartDates.TeamID) ON GroupAgent.AgentID = AgentStartDates.AgentID
WHERE (((History.CallDateTime) Between GetDate() And DateAdd(d,1,GetDate()) 
GROUP BY Groups.GroupName, AgentTeams.TeamName, Agent.Firstname, Agent.Lastname, CRC.Description
ORDER BY Groups.GroupName, AgentTeams.TeamName;
```

Could someone help me fix this or advise me where I'm going wrong?

Adam

Comment: `WHERE (((` Not all these parentheses are closed before the `GROUP BY`

Comment: Most of them can be removed; `WHERE History.CallDateTime Between GetDate() And DateAdd(d,1,GetDate())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the parentheses....

```
          SELECT Groups.GroupName, AgentTeams.TeamName, Agent.Firstname, Agent.Lastname, CRC.Description, Count(History.HistoryID) AS CountOfHistoryID
          FROM ((GroupAgent INNER JOIN Groups ON GroupAgent.GroupID = Groups.GroupID) INNER JOIN ((Agent LEFT JOIN History ON Agent.AgentID = History.AgentID) LEFT JOIN CRC ON History.CRC = CRC.CRC) ON  GroupAgent.AgentID = Agent.AgentID) INNER JOIN (AgentTeams INNER JOIN AgentStartDates ON  AgentTeams.TeamID = AgentStartDates.TeamID) ON GroupAgent.AgentID = AgentStartDates.AgentID
          WHERE (((History.CallDateTime) Between GetDate() And DateAdd(d,1,GetDate()))) 
          GROUP BY Groups.GroupName, AgentTeams.TeamName, Agent.Firstname, Agent.Lastname, CRC.Description
          ORDER BY Groups.GroupName, AgentTeams.TeamName;
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: it has no given the error which is great, It has displayed This table is empty. hmmmmmm

Comment: As far as i known, i dont find anything wrong in the query...but as mentioned in comments you can remove parantheses...will it harm your query?